# JSON encoding problems ios 5

Tags: iphone, json, ios5, encoding

Ok, I should explain better the problem.
I'am developing an iPhone application to display data. Data are obtained from a Mysql database using a php file.

Here, I show the code of PHP file:

```
<?php
header("text/html; charset=utf-8");
//Credenciales de la BBDD
$db = "json";
$host = 'localhost';
$username = "dpbataller";
$password = '1234';

//Conectamos al servidor de la Base de datos
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("No se puede conectar");
//Seleccionamos la BBDD
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se ha podido seleccionar a la base de datos");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
//Lanzamos la consulta
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,nombre from personas");
//Creamos un array para almacenar los resultados
$filas = array();
//Agregamos las filas devueltas al array
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { 
$filas[] = $r;      
}
//Devolvemos el resultado
echo json_encode($filas);
?>
```

At this moment, if I run the script on browser, he returns 
    [{"id":"0","nombre":"Pep\u00e9"}]

Moreover, in the xcode project I have written this code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.0.1.18/mysql_iphone/mostrar_personas.php"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

and the console, returns :
    (
        {
        id = 0;
        nombre = "Pep\U00e9";
    }
   )
Like the browser...This is my problem, because I have noums of persons with accents...

Comment: You are missing the part where you tell us the problem you are having.

Comment: It might be obvious for some of us that you are confused about the unicode characters that appear encoded, but I agree with @rckoenes... Please spend some time to explain your problem properly...

Comment: I have rewritten the problem, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm guessing your problem is that your JSON isn't working, you need to use a NSDictionary not an NSArray:

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

That should solve it.

Comment: It does not work, I think the php file does not correctly return the JSON encoded, could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is looking clunky, actually it's completely wrong. It should look more like this:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Jos \u00e9"
},
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"David"
}
]
```

I suggest you to check the JSON format with one of the many validators out there, like for example: http://json.parser.online.fr/

**EDIT**
It seems you're getting fooled by the debugger...

I tried the following:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [@"[{\"id\":\"0\",\"nombre\":\"Pep\u00e9\"}]" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);

    NSDictionary *item = [json lastObject];
    NSString *nombre = [item objectForKey:@"nombre"];

    NSLog(@"%@", nombre);
```

The first NSLog will print out the escaped char, but the extracted string is actually correctly encoded in UTF8.

**EDIT 2**

You're code is already working, you do not need to change anything

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.0.1.18/mysql_iphone/mostrar_personas.php"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSArray *items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// This will print all the names of people in your JSON.
for (NSDictionary *item in items)
{
    NSLog(@"nombre: %@", [item objectForKey:objectForKey:@"nombre"]);
}
```

Comment: The information is returned by a php script. If I run the script on the browser, I can see this [{"id":"0","nombre":"Pep\u00e9"}]

Comment: Ok! this code works, but ... How could adapt it to my code? Because I am getting the JSON objects from a URL.Is possible? Thanks

Comment: Ok! It works! But I need to save the names of people in an array, not to show it.
How I can do this?
Thank you very much, you are helping me a lot ..

Comment: You should accept the answer and maybe start a new one. I'd also suggest you to take a look to some [objective-c documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/objc.pdf) before moving forward.

Comment: Thanks! You has been very nice!